# button extension in f# canopy

Tags: f#, canopy, canopy-web-testing

I'm trying to make a general button extension in f# and canopy.

as you know we can click a button like this in canopy

```
click (//button[contains(text(),'save')])[last()]
```

But I'm trying to do something like this.

```
let _button value = sprintf "(//button[contains(text(),'%s')])[last()]" value
let button value = _button value 
click button "save"
```

but this gives ***This value is not a function and cannot be applied***

Any great ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `_button`?

Comment: @NghiaBui typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button` is a function with signature: `string -> string`

`click` is a function with signature: `string -> something`

So, you cannot pass `button` to `click`, you should write:

```
click (button "save")
```

or

```
click <| button "save"
```

Idiomatically, I would rewrite your code as:

```
let button = sprintf "(//button[contains(text(),'%s')])[last()]"
click (button "save")
```